# Switching speed of MOSFET and BJT

Tags: mosfet, switches, bjt

I've read on the internet that MOSFET is faster switching device than bipolar transistor, however, i don't understand why. Considering the fact that transconductance of bjt is grater than transconductance of MOSFET  i thought that BJT is faster and can operate better at higher frequencies.

Can anyone clarify this a bit? Any answers appreciated!

Comment: Where on the internet did you read this - supply a link or embed the text

Comment: What Andy says and also: you're mixing things up, transconductance is mostly relevant when using a transistor as a signal **amplifier**, not so much when using it as a **switch**. The fastest (highest bandwidth) MOSFETs and BJTs are not very useable for switching. The fastest transistors for switching are often useless as a signal amplifier. You will need to study a some more to understand the (speed) limitations of each type of device when used as a switch (or an amplifier). Voting as too broad.

Comment: https://www.edaboard.com/showthread.php?318174-why-the-switching-speed-of-BJT-is-greater-than-MOSFET People in the answers are claiming that MOSFET is faster than a BJT. However, i may have asked the wrong question (sorry about that, i am going to edit that), what i wanted to know is, why MOSFET is faster than bipolar (i am not considering any other devices other than MOSFET and bipolar)?

Comment: For digital switching the mosfet is faster because it does not experience the same type of saturation that BJT's do. A saturated BJT takes a long time to turn off. But when used in amplifiers, saturation is avoided. For amplifiers, you cannot say that CMOS is faster than BJT as a blaket statement.